# WP How can I combine multipe query?

Tags: wordpress

I like to combine multiple query into one result.

$args_a and $args_b in below code are simplified to summarize my question.  I like to combine 2 or more query in one result.

They should not be overwritten each other, so I think "merge" is not proper method to combine this case.

Now, how can I combine them together?

```
<?php
$args_a = array(
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'paged' => $paged,
'category_name' => 'shinmatsudo',
'category__in' => array( 227 ),
'category__not_in' => array( 3 ),
'meta_query' => array(
                      'relation' => 'AND',
                                          array(
                                                'key'     => '1b',
                                                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                                 ),

                                           array(
                                                'key'     => '1d',
                                                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                                 ),                        
                      ), 
);?>


<?php
$args_b = array(
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'category_name' => 'matsudo',
'category__in' => array( 329 ),
'category__not_in' => array( 3 ),
'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'and',
                                array(
                                'key'=> '2a',
                                'value' => array('2020-02-01' , '2020-06-01'),
                                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                'type' => 'DATE',
                                ),
                    ),
);
?>

<?php
global $post;
$my_posts= get_posts($args_b);
$my_posts= get_posts($args_a);     
     
foreach($my_posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you write up your expectation as SQL (even SQL is wrong no problem which helps to understand what you are trying) so that we can create correct `WP_Query`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply !  Im sorry I can't write SQL things.  I like to show result from query $args_a and query $args_b in one result.  Like this: result of  $args_a = article 1, article 2, article 3.  Result of $args_b is article 4 and article 5.  Show them in one result by date order like this.  Article 3, article 5, article 4, artice 2, article 1.

Comment: Now I think 'merge' is not proper usage in my case.  Maybe using get_posts($args_a) and ($args_b) is the way to make it ???   Somebody knows how to combine get posts?

Comment: If you are going to have $args that have different criteria, then you will need to do each query and merge the *results* rather than the args.

Comment: Thank yoiu for your comment, Fluffy Kitten.  I can not get exact meaning of criteria in php .  I just found "merge" will overwrite things, so I think I better to look for other way to combine all result together.

Comment: I changed code.  Now somebody please tell me how to make it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem your code has is you are overwriting `$my_posts` variable. Think about what your code is doing:

```
global $post;
$my_posts= get_posts($args_b);
$my_posts= get_posts($args_a);
```

You are reassigning `$my_posts` to the second `get_posts` so the `$args_b` will always be overwritten.

You can try using `array_merge()` to take the results of both `get_posts` and combine them into a single array.

```
global $post;
$my_posts= array_merge( get_posts($args_b), get_posts($args_a) );
     
foreach($my_posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi disinfor.  Thank you for your help evertime!  Now I understand how to merge result by get_posts.  Im wondering is it possible to make them togehter by WP_Query ?

Comment: @cwhiro no you can't merge them, because you are trying to get 9 of each category and there is no way to specify that in the query args.

Comment: Thank you disinfor.  Now I changed code that is easy to understand for me however it does not work well.  Is this completely wrong?  or you can make it work like the way by get_posts?

Comment: That is completely wrong and will not work. Please don't update this question, since this answer won't make sense to future visitors since you changed the original. Post a new question with the working code, but ask what you **want** to change with it. Edit this question back to how it was since I think it can actually help other users.

Comment: @cwhiro I rolled back to your previous edit so this answer makes sense. Open a new question with what you want to do with the working code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advise of question rule. Now I opened new question.